# How do I headless install Ubuntu 10.10 Server

Tags: headless, ubuntu-10.10

I installed Centos 5.5 on a headless server. The BIOS supports console redirection, so all I needed to do was: 1) Connect over a serial cable, 2) adjust the BIOS, 3) put the CD in, and  4) at the boot prompt, type:

```
linux console=ttyS0,115200n8
```

On Ubuntu 10.10, I tried the same technique. Even before the `boot:` prompt, I received an error message:

```
graphics initialization failed
Error setting up gfxboot
boot:
```

and when I tried to the same command as on Centos, I received the error:

```
Could not find kernel image: linux
```

I then looked at the isolinux directory on the CD, and all the boot menus had something like `/install/vmlinuz`, so I tried:

```
/install/vmlinuz console=ttyS0,115200n8
```

But that fails with a kernel panic

```
[    3.271958] Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknow
n-block(104,1)
[    3.280699] Pid: 1, comm: swapper Not tainted 2.6.35-22-generic #33-Ubuntu
```

Farther up the console output, I saw the error:

```
[    3.185400] VFS: Cannot open root device "(null)" or unknown-block(104,1)
[    3.192380] Please append a correct "root=" boot option; here are the availab
le partitions:
```

I'm going to keep trying, but I would welcome any advice on how to get Ubuntu 10.10 installed on my headless server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the isolinux .cfg files, I came up with something to try:

```
/install/vmlinuz console=ttyS0,115200n8 file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu-server.seed initrd=/install/initrd.gz quiet --
```

It worked. I got a text based set of install menus.

I actually prefer seeing all the output when the system boots, so I also successfully used:

```
/install/vmlinuz console=ttyS0,115200n8 file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu-server.seed initrd=/install/initrd.gz
```

As an aside, if you need to run in rescue mode

```
/install/vmlinuz console=ttyS0,115200n8 initrd=/install/initrd.gz rescue/enable=true
```